# Custom Monitor Position in Xubuntu, monitors.xml Equivalent

Tags: xubuntu, xorg, multiple-monitors

I have three monitors and would like to be able to set my background to span all three screens.

However, my side monitors (smaller screens) are lower than the middle one. In Linux Mint I was able to edit the monitors.xml file to set custom height, for example:
`<x>3120</x> <y>34</y>`

Is there an equivalent of monitors.xml in xubuntu 14.04?

I do not want to set up an xorg.conf file to achieve this. If no solution is possible, I am still content to do three individual backgrounds or fix up the background image in GIMP to meet my needs.  Much thanks in advance.

Comment: There is an equivalent file in ~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/displays.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First solution:
Settings > Settings Editor > displays
Then I double clicked next to 'Y' at the appropriate places to change the height.

Second solution:
@Adriano Silva, Thank you.

```
~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/displays.xml
```

Third solution (only if the other two do not work):
1. I installed arandr.
2. I adjusted the approximate height I wanted in arandr.
3. I then saved the configuration to an .sh script.
4. I opened the script and adjusted the two side monitors to the precise height (--pos) I wanted.
5. I then created a new Application Autostart item and copied the command there (example pasted below).

`xrandr --output DisplayPort-1-0 --off --output VGA-1 --mode 1440x900 --pos 0x30 --rotate normal --output VGA-1-0 --off --output DVI-0 --mode 1440x900 --pos 3120x34 --rotate normal --output HDMI-0 --mode 1680x1050 --pos 1440x0 --rotate normal`

Answer (score 0):

I was having all sorts of multiple monitor problems in the last couple versions of xubuntu, which for some reason went away when I would log in with straight XFCE. Go figure.

Comment: I had a bit of a time getting the GUI (Display Settings) to correctly set up the monitors in xubuntu. I would change the position or resolution of one and the graphics would get all distorted, and it would mess things up. Finally, I realized that I needed to disable (deselecting 'Use this output') two of the three monitors. Then I enabled them one by one and set up each one by one. After that it set up perfect with no issues.